# How to convert a list to a string

Tags: c, embedded

**Problem in C programming**

I have following list:

`int a[] = {0,0,1,0,0,1,0,2}`

How do i convert following list items to char variable *b*?

Like this:

`printf(%c, b)
OUTPUT: 00100102`

I need this for printing the values of list in embedded system lcd screen where normal print options aren't available. Couldn't find similar example from www.stackoverflow.com. Vice versa there were many solutions to convert a string into a list.

Comment: If you're sure they're all single-digit numbers, add `\x30` to each value in the array.

Comment: I'm sorry, i didn't understand what you meant. Could you clarify?

Comment: In ASCII, the character `0` has a value of `\x30`, `1` has `\x31`, etc. So to print the single digit value, you would have to add `\x30` (or, as @unwind put it, `'0'`) to the number you want to print.

Comment: What is the range of values for individual `a[]` members: `0` to `9`, or `INT_MIN` to `INT_MAX` or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int a[] = {0,0,1,0,0,1,0,2};
    const char *table = "0123456789";
    size_t size = sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a);
    char *b = malloc(size+1);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;++i)
        b[i]=table[a[i]];
    b[i]='\0';
    printf("%s\n", b);
    free(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int a = [0,0,1,0,0,1,0,2]
```

That is not valid C. Perhaps you meant:

```
const int a[] = { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2 };
```

Converting a decimal digit to a printable character in C is easy, just add `'0'`:

```
printf("%c", '0' + a[0]);
```

will print `0`.

Comment: Adding '0' is a way to manually convert a decimal digit into the ASCII representation.  But it only works for integers in the range of 0 to 9.  Why not let printf() do the conversion for you by using the "%d" format specifier.  `printf("%d", a[0]);` works for all integer values.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the elements of your array, and `printf()` each one, considering it as an offset from `'0'`:

```
/*

'0' + 0 = '0'
'0' + 1 = '1'
'0' + 2 = '2'

*/

const int a[] = {0,0,1,0,0,1,0,2};
const int count = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
int i;

for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    printf("%c", '0' + a[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

Answer (score -1):

When you convert each value in an array of `int` to a corresponding value in an array of `char`, you just have an array of `char`.  When you append the null terminator `\0` (or 0) to the array of `char`, it becomes a C string.

```
int a[] = {0,0,1,0,0,1,0,2}; //use curly braces to assign values to new array.
char b[sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])+1];//Accomodates any size of a.  note extra space for terminating \0
int i;
//EDIT 5 following lines
b[0]=0; //ensure string is null terminated
for(i=0;i<sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);i++)
{
    sprintf(b, "%s%d", b, a[i]);//copy one char per loop to concatenate string with all elements of `a`  
}
```

Now you have a string, sized according to number of array elements in `a` that looks like:
"00100102"
***In memory*** you would see ***|48|48|49|48|48|49|48|50|0|***
(the integer values of each character representation of the integers 0, 1, & 2, with the null character 0 in the last position to mark the end of string.)

***Note also***, the phrase `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` is used to get the number of elements in an array.

Comment: down voter care to comment? (or is this my old friend?)

Comment: probably,`sprintf(b[i], "%c", a[0]);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY - I believe you are right.  Thank you.  I will edit to fix.

Comment: Not been able to fix. it is to try to compile actually executed.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY - Okay, thank you.  This last edit went through a compiler.  I was without a compiler on the previous entries.